# pointer assignment to another type of variable

Tags: c, pointers

I am running simple program.

Here is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
char c,*cc;
int i;
long l;
float f;

c='z';
i=15;
l=77777;
f=3.14;
cc=&c;

printf("c=%c cc=%u\n",*cc,cc);
cc=&i;
printf("i=%d cc=%u\n",*cc,cc);
cc=&l;
printf("l=%ld cc=%u\n",*cc,cc);
cc=&f;
printf("f=%f cc=%u\n",*cc,cc);

return (getch());
}
```

So as per my knowledge the size of the integer remains higher than char so when i am assigning the integer variable to char pointer it must point only first byte of the integer variable because cc is a char pointer. And so when i run the output only the first printf line should give the correct output the other lines must print some addresses or some garbage value.

But in my case here the second line printf also gives the correct value which is 15 i assigned to integer variable while i think it must give garbage value.please tell me how it happens?

here is my output.

```
c=z cc=2686791
i=15 cc=2686780
l=-47 cc=2686776
f=0.000000 cc=4199093
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when i am assigning the integer variable to char pointer it must point only first byte of the integer variable

Then why is it surprising that the second line prints 15? The number 15 fits into one byte, the least significant byte of the `int`. And the LSB is exactly the byte with the lowest memory address if your machine is little-endian (which it probably and apparently is).

---

And use `%p` to print pointers, `%u` is for unsigned integers. Read the documentaion of `printf()`.

Comment: so if i will assign the larger value in integer i then it will cause error? am i right?

Comment: @google It won't cause an error, it will truncate the number taking it modulo 256. (or some other number if your `char` appears to be more than 8 bits wide.)

Comment: ya sorry its my mistake in comment it will print some other number.

Answer (score 2):

The byte layout of the integer `15` is `[0x0f][0x00][0x00][0x00]`, so when you dereference `cc` you are getting the content of the first byte (which happens to be 15).

To see a difference, try the case `i=1000` and you should see `-24` (the byte at address `&i` is `0xe8`, which is `-24` when interpreted as a signed byte)

Comment: what happens in the case of float?

Comment: @google floats are generally stored with the [IEEE 754 standard format](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/)